# Javascript On Click Syntax Error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a line of javascript which calls a function called "divClicked". But the targeted div is dynamically generated, so I think I need to use an on click function instead. What is wrong with my syntax?

Original line which doesn't work due to dynamically generated content.

```
$(".js-contentEditable").click(divClicked);
```

New Line with syntax error

```
$("#generator").on("click", ".js-contentEditable", function(divClicked);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it certainly is a syntax error, but you're close:

```
$("#generator").on("click", ".js-contentEditable", divClicked);
```

When you've already got a defined function and you can reference it by name, then you can pass it to another function just with the name. You only need the `function` keyword when you're defining a **new** function. (It occurs to me that  when I say, "a new function", I mean a function that didn't exist before. I do **not** mean a function intended to be used with `new`; that keyword has nothing to do with the problem at hand here. Don't be confused please :)